# Why are only 2 versions of the .net framework available for my Azure web app?

Tags: .net, azure

I have developed my web application using dot net framework 4.5.2

I set up a web app at AustraliaSouthEast to deploy to

I notice that the only frameworks available for this web app are 3.5 and 4.6

Why is that?

I am looking at a combo box called .Net Framework version in Application Settings -> General Settings.

Is there a way I can enable framework 4.5.2?

Comment: FYI, .NET framework 4.5.1 will be unsupported from January 12th, 2016 on.  You should upgrade to at least 4.5.2 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually .Net FX evolves very incrementally, that implies that new version will contain/support prior version most of the times.

Major changes in Fx ocurs -usually- when there are new changes at CLR level, in the current maturity state of the platform thats very unusual, last breaking changes ocurred in

Fx2 (too much breaking: generics, memory , GC etc)
Fx 3.5 (changes to allow thinks like linq, lambda expressions, delegates etc )

There are no major or significant breaking changes in framework 4.6 comparing with 4.5.1.

All the changes are minor or edge, that means that prior applications running in Fx 4.5.* will need minor or even none modifications to run normally on fx 4.6.

You can verify the changes in these links:

### [Runtime Changes in the .NET Framework 4.6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833125(v=vs.110).aspx)

### [Retargeting Changes in the .NET Framework 4.6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833123(v=vs.110).aspx)

--
In the rare case you need specifically 4.5.1 you can attach to your solution the binaries for 4.5.1 in bin folder, this could work but breaks the support and SLA for Azure Web Apps.